Business Central No. Series API
In BC we have several number series for purchase invoices and Invoice Nos is set to Number series which you cannot use for generating numbers (lets say N-FAK is code for this No. series)
No. series which you can use for generating numbers is N-FAP.
I have coppied Purchase Invoice API page and made some changes
I wanted to pass noSeriesCode as api parameter to generate new number from this series, but it does not seem to work
Shortened version of my api page here:
using ...

page 50102 "Purch Invoices"
{
    ...
    PageType = API;
    SourceTable = "Purch. Inv. Entity Aggregate";

    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            repeater(Group)
            {
                field(number; Rec."No.")
                {
                    Caption = 'No.';
                    Editable = true;

                    trigger OnValidate()
                    begin
                        RegisterFieldSet(Rec.FieldNo("No."));
                    end;
                }
                field(postingDate; Rec."Posting Date")
                {
                    Caption = 'Posting Date';

                    trigger OnValidate()
                    begin
                        RegisterFieldSet(Rec.FieldNo("Posting Date"));
                    end;
                }
                
                field(noSeriesCode; noSeriesCode)
                {
                    Caption = 'Number series for number generation';
                }
            }
        }
    }


    trigger OnInsertRecord(BelowxRec: Boolean): Boolean
    var
        PurchInvAggregator: Codeunit "Purch. Inv. Aggregator";
    begin
        GenerateNumber();
        ...
    end;

    local procedure GenerateNumber()
    var
        purchaseHeader: Record "Purch. Inv. Entity Aggregate";
    begin
        if Rec."No." = '' then begin
            Rec."No." := NoSeries.GetNextNo(noSeriesCode, Rec."Posting Date");
        end;
    end;
    var
        noSeriesCode: code[20];
        NoSeries: Codeunit "No. Series";
}

When I use this code and provide noSeriesCode = N-FAP, it correctly generates number, but record is not created (Purchase Header record) and error is thrown:
"It is not possible to assign numbers automatically. If you want the program to assign numbers automatically, please activate Default Nos. in No. Series N-FAK"
For me it seems like it is ignoring my generated number and is still trying to use default number series.
I have tried several modifications to this code (like generating number in OnValidate method of number field, but nothing works)
